# Writing promise based HTTP request using Async/Await

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to rewrite the following HTTP request example from the Node manual to use Async/Await rather than promises? I am familiar with the return new promise method with resolve/reject but would rather use async/await.

```
    const postData = querystring.stringify({
      'msg': 'Hello World!'
    });

    const options = {
      hostname: 'www.google.com',
      port: 80,
      path: '/upload',
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
      }
    };

    const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
      console.log(`STATUS: ${res.statusCode}`);
      console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(res.headers)}`);
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
      });
      res.on('end', () => {
        console.log('No more data in response.');
      });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`problem with request: ${e.message}`);
    });

    // write data to request body
    req.write(postData);
    req.end();
```

Comment: You cannot use `async`/`await` *instead* of promises. You can only use promises with `async`/`await` syntax.

Comment: If it's a Promise, sure you can rewrite it using `async/await`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you posted doesn't use promises (`req` is an event emitter, more specifically a [ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_clientrequest) instance), so no you cannot use `async`/`await` syntax here.

> I am familiar with the `return new Promise` method with resolve/reject but would rather use async/await

No, you cannot use `async`/`await` instead of the [`Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) anyway. You can use it as syntactic sugar for `then` calls only.

Comment: Thanks for the clarity. Cheers